# Resource not found by maven plugin code when building project with module having the plugin

Tags: java, maven, module, classpath

I have a Maven project MyProject having several other projects defined as modules in its pom.

One module is called MyPluginProject and it contains the code and definition of a custom maven plugin. This plugin needs to search for a resource file using a utility class Utils in yet another module called MyUtilityProject.

The Utils class (its method) first attempts to find the file on the class path using Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource) and if no result, it attempts a new FileInputStream(resource). If it is still not found, a runtime exception is thrown.

A third module is called MyTestProject and in its pom it references the custom plugin (defined in build/plugins/plugin).

1) When executing a mvn clean install on MyTestProject, the plugin is executed and it has the utility method search for a resource 'myFile.txt' which is in the root of MyTestProject. The class path attempt getResourceAsStream does not find the file, but FileInputStream does. The build succeeds and all is fine.

2) When executing a mvn clean install on the entire thing, MyProject, the file (still in the root of MyTestProject) is not found. The build fails because the runtime exception is thrown.

However it is found when I define the file as 'MyTestProject/myFile.txt', but I do not want that.

How can I accomplish the file 'myFile.txt' in the root of module MyTestProject to be found in both cases? Probably by making sure the class loader has the correct class path? But how to do that?

**Edit 1:**
The modules are also physically nested in the main project. So this is the structure:

```
MyProject
|-MyPluginProject (contains the plugin definition in pom + code)
|-MyUtilityProject (does the resource lookup)
|-MyTestProject (simulates usage of the plugin in MyPluginProject)
     |-myFile.txt
```

**Edit 2:**
I did discover that when building the parent MyProject the classpath contains the full absolute path to the jars in the targets of the Eclipse project locations of MyPluginProject and MyUtilityProject.

However when building the child MyTestProject, the classpath contains the full absolute path to these project's jars in the local Maven repository, not the ones in the Eclipse workspace locations.

Both classpaths are missing the MyTestProject jar. And I am using mvn outside Eclipse.

Comment: Where is the plugin defined? In both poms (module and parent)? Do you have defined child module in parent pom and parent tag in child module?

Comment: All modules mentioned have the parent tag set to the parent project. In the parent project all modules are listed as 'modules'. The parent project has no definition of the maven plugin (why would that be necessary? The plugin is executed, it just cannot find te resource).